# Use Azure service principal on VM

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-service-principal

I have a service account that I am using together with node and it works as expected, `msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret` however when I deploy it to our VM with the same client-id,secret etc. it stops working. It keeps telling me that
`The client '***' with object id '***' does not have authorization to perform action.`

Do I need to connect the service-principal to the VM somehow? I suspect that a service-principal is not available to be used on a VM is this correct? I suspect this since the client-id I enter is different from the client-id from the error-log

**Edit:**
Here is the part of the code where the error is thrown:

```js
transformCreate = await mediaServicesClient.transforms.createOrUpdate(
  resourceGroup,
  accountName,
  transformName,
  {
    name: transformName,
    outputs: [
      {
        preset: presetDefinition,
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

Which is not very informative, however the error is thrown here since this is the first part of the code which is trying to create something which the VM clearly does not have access to.

Comment: Did you enable managed identity on the VM?

Comment: @AndriyBilous I guess not, do you refer to `identity -> System Assigned` and then turn it on?

Comment: Yes, enable identity -> System Assigned

Comment: @AndriyBilous I still end up with the same error. Do I need to grant the VM access to the service-principal or something?

Comment: Give access(Contributor permissions) service-principal to the VM

Comment: Could you show the complete code that you got the error?

Comment: @AndriyBilous I did, however I did not seem to do the trick.

Comment: @JoyWang I edited my post and added some code to it, especially the snippet which is throwing the error